# How to get the background fill to align with the right of the textField (mui react)

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a styling applied to a Text Fields Input Adornment (react mui)

[image: Example]

As you can see there is a gap between the orange background and the right edge of the text field.

I am not sure how to close this gap.

The styled component looks like this

```
const StoreTextField = styled(TextField)(({ theme }) => ({
    '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
      paddingLeft: 0,
      marginRight:0
    },
    '& .MuiInputAdornment-root': {
      backgroundColor: '#f7b500',
      padding: '28px 28px',
      borderTopLeftRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius + 'px',
      borderBottomLeftRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius + 'px',
    },
  }));
```

Can anyone let me know what I am missing please